# jQuery validation is not working for Google autocomplete enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-validate

I am using google autocomplete and jQuery validation in a form and it is working fine for below cases.

1. A user types the location, using autocomplete he selects the value by mouse click.
2. A user types the location and moves to next field or clicks anywhere then location field becomes empty. (Because the requirement is user should select the value and they can't type and submit random values)

Above conditions are working fine. But

1. A user types the location, selects the value by click enter button. In this condition, values are coming but still, jQuery validation is showing `please enter the location` (Please check the below image). When a user clicks somewhere or moves the cursor to the next field then only the error message becomes hide.

If users select the value by clicking enter, it should not display the error message as values are selected. If the values are not selected then displaying error message is fine.

Please help me. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F7Kbf/317/)

```js
$( "form" ).validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert( "Successful submission" );         
    }
});

$("#locationTextField").on("blur", function () { 0 == $(this).val().trim().length ? ($("#locationTextField").parents("div").removeClass("has-error").addClass("success"), $("#locationTextField-error").hide()) : $("#locationTextField").removeClass("success").addClass("has-error")
    });
```

```css
form > div {
    margin: 1em;
}
form button {
    width: 100%;
}
label { display: block; }
input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em;
}
button {
    padding: 0.2em;
}
 
label.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&dummy=.js"></script>
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Location:</label>
        <input type="text" id="locationTextField" style="color:#555 !important;" onChange="return validateCity()" placeholder="" name="location" class="form-control" required maxlength="150" data-msg-required="Please enter your location">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="name" class="form-control" required maxlength="150" data-msg-required="Please enter your name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function initialize() {
    var e = document.getElementById("locationTextField");
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(e);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function validateCity() {
    return searchfield = $("#locationTextField").val(), "" == searchfield || null == searchfield ? !1 : ($("#locationTextField").val(""), !1)
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: try `focusout` instead of  `blur`

Comment: I tried `focusout `,`live` and etc no use. Please someone help me :(

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the script that is handling the autocomplete.  You'll need to first find a callback function that happens after an item is selected from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem is caused by the fact that the jQuery Validate plugin is only triggered by user interactions such as `onkeyup`, `focusout`, etc.  Since you are programmatically changing the value of this field, validation is always skipped.

The solution it to simply trigger validation programmatically using the plugin's `.valid()` method.  However, since the field is populated by the Google Autocomplete function, you need to find a built-in event that you can leverage to call `.valid()`.  Google provides the `place_changed` event that will work for this.

- Create a Google listener that checks for the `place_changed` event.
- Use the event to call `.valid()` whenever the location is changed.  The field will be validated and the errors will automatically show/hide as normal.
- Remove your inline `onChange` function.  It's not needed.
- Remove your entire `validateCity` function.  It's also not needed.
- Remove your `blur` handler function.  It's not needed since the plugin is designed to handle these changes automatically.

The new code:

```
function initialize() {
    var e = document.getElementById("locationTextField");
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(e);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        $('#locationTextField').valid();  // trigger validation after place selected
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);  // initialize Google Maps

$("form").validate({  // initialize Validate plugin
    // options
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/x0jt2jux/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/x0jt2jux/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sparky. I tested the demo link. Its working fine `enter button`. But still, users can type and submit random values. The requirement is users should select the values from Google autocomplete. Can you please improve the answer?

Comment: @acmsohail, this answer took some time and effort.  Have you not done any more research yourself at all?  What steps have you taken, how much time and effort, to solve the rest of your problem?

Comment: Hi @Sparky I spend two days to fix this issue. After your answer, I realized the actual issue and I improved my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot @Sparky.

I've been using variables but I think I will switch to your method, this is clearly the real method to do it. Anyway, if someone needs mine (even if I suggest to use the answer from Sparky), here is how it works:

(on page load, set `googleAdressFill = 0`, and then, when `fillInAddress()` is executed, set `googleAdressFill = 1`)

Then, add a method using `addMethod` function for jQuery validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myMethod", function(value, element) {
   if (googleAdressFill === 0) 
       return this.optional(element);
   else
       return true;
   }, "You need to enter and select address from suggestion.");
```

And declare the new rule method in jQuery validation options.

```
  rules: { nameOfInput: { myMethod: true } }
```